# Open SSIS solution developed in SSDT 2013 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I've been given an SSIS solution which was originally developed in SSDT 2013 (SQL Server 2014) which ideally I'd like to develop further in Visual Studio 2017 (with Integration Services component installed) rather than having to install SSDT 2013 myself as it's another tool the department doesn't really want.

I've managed to successfully open the solution and I seem to be able to view everything but when I try to build it I receive the following error:

[image: Error Message]

If somebody is able to tell me quickly this isn't possible then I can enjoy my weekend and stop this terrible search

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the TargetSeverVersion of the solution set to SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Yes the TargetServerVersion is set to 2014 :-(